# Detect click action when 'file open dialog' popping up

Tags: javascript, autotest

I think I have two questions. The second question is based on the first one.

First, I want to know about using js to detect click action. Assume I have a button `selectImage`, which is used to upload local image picture, i.e. after click the `selectImage` button, one `file open dialog` will pop up to let me choose the uploading file.

My question is: if we use js listener to listen to the click action of `selectImage`, when we click the it and `file open dialog` popped up, could we be noticed that the *click action* happened?

My second question is: if we can't detect the *click action* happen, which may be due to the process of choosing *uploading file* didn't finish, is there one way in js to detect the success of this *click action*?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/kLmb7u2n/

Comment: Have a look at this question, it has both vanilla JS and jQuery examples http://stackoverflow.com/q/8451771/1585957

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function on clicking the file input button as

```
 <input type="file" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

And the make a function in javascript as

```
function myFunction(){
  alert('click action happened');
}
```

Check snippet

```js
function myFunction(){
  alert('click action happened');
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `addEventListener()` to the get the `click` event of input

```js
var file = document.getElementById("file")
file.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Now select a file");
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />
```