# Detect ANY click that might open a link without knowing which element does that

Tags: javascript, onclick

For my chrome extension I need to detect any click on any element on the page that might open a link and, let's say, show an alert box. There are plenty of websites where you might click on a video player or anywhere on the page and a new page will open (live streams etc.).

Links I've found useful : 
[How to detect if user it trying to open a link in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087368/how-to-detect-if-user-it-trying-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab)

[How to detect Link clicks (text, images, etc) with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451771/how-to-detect-link-clicks-text-images-etc-with-javascript)

So far the information I found presumes that I know which elements on the page will open the link. This javascript will be injected on the website and I do NOT know which click and where will open a new link. Is there a way to execute some code AFTER the user clicks such an element AND BEFORE the link is opened?

Comment: Pretty hard, because pretty much anything can open a link. Either assume that any click could do so, or monkeypatch `onclick` and `addEventListener` *before any of the page JS can run*, if that's in your power (and also look for inline handlers on the clicked element and all ancestors)